# Compiling OpenSSH without "consolekit.patch"

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, compile, sshd

I'm currently encountering issues with some tools that connect via SSH to a remote machine (Eclipse's remote deployment) to deploy files automatically. Around 90% of the time, when I initiate the session, the connection to the remote machine is immediately killed and I have to retry. I believe that I have traced the issue back to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/1334916), where the OP explains that the issue is caused by something called `ConsoleKit`. They then say that (emphasis mine):

> The same script works fine **if sshd is compiled without consolekit.patch**

What does this mean, and how do I go about doing it? I have tried using versions of OpenSSH (`sshd` on the server) from as far back as v5.0 in hopes that this faulty code won't be included, but it still has this issue. So, I'm hoping that I can compile it myself without including this patch to figure out what's going on.

I don't see any aptly-named patch files or build configuration options, so I'm really not sure where to begin.

Comment: That bug report is about an Ubuntu-specific version of the ssh _server_ program sshd. In other words, this is about the ssh software no the remote system you are connecting to, not the local system that you're connecting from. Is the remote system Ubuntu? Are you trying different versions of sshd on the remote system? Are you _able_ to update the sshd program on the remote system? You say you've tried different versions of OpenSSH, but what _specifically did you do here?

Comment: I understand that this is about the server; I was testing versions of `sshd`. Both the client and the server are running recent versions of Ubuntu. I have updated the question to reflect this clarification (the tags already explain this)

Comment: To test older versions, I would download a specific version of their source code, run`./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`.

Comment: Where are you downloading this source code from?

Comment: I was getting it from what appears to be their official source mirror: ftp://ftp3.usa.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/

Comment: Well, there you go then. You're building a version that doesn't contain any Ubuntu-specific patches, presumably including this consolekit patch.

Comment: So, you're saying that I _am_ including the bad patch? If so, where can I get the Ubuntu-specific source code?